# Polish Character Displaying English Issue Using Itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

I am using some polish character in my pdf and i used some external font.

I am using phrase for displaying text in pdf, so when i write any polish character in phrase it display english character. I am using this code.

```
        table = new PdfPTable(1);
        table.TotalWidth = 500f;
        table.WidthPercentage = 100;
        cell.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;
        Color colorPurple = new Color(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#338B94"));
        BaseFont custm_fnts = BaseFont.CreateFont(fontpath + "TitilliumWeb-Bold.ttf", BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED); //Font font = new Font(customfont, 52);
        Font newfntbldh2 = new Font(custm_fnts, 18, Font.NORMAL, colorPurple);
        cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase("Najważniejsze zdarzenia", newfntbldh2), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.AddCell(cell);
        document.Add(table);
```

This line cell=PhraseCell i use polish words 'Najważniejsze' but it will show not exactly that i passed it will show in english text.

How to keep that polish character as same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the font encoding `BaseFont.IDENTITY_H` and it will work. CP1252 doesn't have all the required polish chars.